# How to authenticate and authorize based on membership of group in Active Directory

Tags: node.js, active-directory-group

I'm a beginner in Nodejs and I'm trying to include Active Directory authentication in my web application. Also,I'm trying to check if the user belongs to a certain group before allowing him to us it.
I'm trying to follow [this article](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-activedirectory) but it is not working with me:

I used the below code:

```
var passport = require('passport')
var ActiveDirectoryStrategy = require('passport-activedirectory')
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory')

var ad = new ActiveDirectory({
    url: 'ldap://my.domain.com',
    baseDN: 'DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com',
    username: 'readuser@my.domain.com',
    password: 'readuserspassword'
})

passport.use(new ActiveDirectoryStrategy({
    integrated: false,
    ldap: ad
    }, function (profile, ad, done) {
        ad.isUserMemberOf(profile._json.dn, 'AccessGroup', function (err, isMember) 
        {
            if (err) return done(err)
            return done(null, profile)
        })
}))
```

and as a middleware, I used this code:

```
  var opts = { failWithError: true }
  app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', opts), 
  function(req, res) {
      res.json(req.user)
  }, function (err) {
      res.status(401).send('Not Authenticated')
  })
```

However I am receiving this error when I try to open the "login" page:

> AuthenticationError: Unauthorized
>       at allFailed (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:172:21)
>       at attempt (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:180:28)
>       at Strategy.strategy.fail (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:297:9)
>       at D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\passport-activedirectory\index.js:143:22
>       at onFind (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\activedirectory\lib\activedirectory.js:1334:21)
>       at onSearchEnd (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\activedirectory\lib\activedirectory.js:506:21)
>       at EventEmitter. (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\activedirectory\lib\activedirectory.js:540:7)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at sendResult (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1389:22)
>       at messageCallback (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1421:16)
>       at Parser.onMessage (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\client\client.js:1089:14)
>       at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
>       at Parser.emit (events.js:211:7)
>       at Parser.write (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\messages\parser.js:111:8)
>       at end (D:\Java Script\NodeJs\Printer\node_modules\ldapjs\lib\messages\parser.js:66:19)

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of create an instance of active directory (var ad = ... bla bla), try to set ldap key value on passport strategy:

```
ldap: {
   url: 'ldap://my.domain.com',
   baseDN: 'DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com',
   username: 'readuser@my.domain.com',
   password: 'readuserspassword'
}
```

the authentication method should be some like this:

```
router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
   passport.authenticate('ActiveDirectory', { failWithError: true }, function(err, user, info) {
     if (err) { return next(JSON.stringify(err)); }
     if (!user) { return res.send({ success : false, message : 'authentication failed' }); }
     return res.status(200).json({ user });
})(req, res, next); });
```